# How can I get notified when my ListView gets populated?

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a ListActivity and am filling the list view with an adapter as such:

```
// SimpleAdapter adapter = ...
setListAdapter( adapter );
setContentView( R.layout.main );

ListView lv = getListView();
```

lv seems to have zero children, even though I'm populating it with children from a layout and the adapter has many items in it.  I noticed that if I wait some time -- when the list view is rendered fully -- it does have children.  How can I get notified of when the list view is fully ready to be used?

Comment: You mean the adapter has initially more than zero elements and the data is available, etc. and you still not see the list with the correct data immediately?

Comment: Correct. I'm doing this from a HandlerThread that uses the Activity's looper; in other words, I'm doing this on the UI thread, so I don't think that's what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate your list in the background using an AsyncTask, and then notify yourself once the loading is complete.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {

    m_loaded = false;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
        Log.d("doinBackground", "here");

        // do your loading

        return "";

    }

    // -- gets called just before thread begins
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        m_loaded = true;  //your list is done loading
    }
}
```